# Funcion de ventana SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, transact-sql

tengo la siguiente funcion de ventana

```
DECLARE @Total numeric(18,2) = 45689

SELECT 
t.NumeroRegistro
,t.Orden
,t.Fecha
,t.Valor

,@Total - SUM(t.Valor) OVER(Order By t.Fecha,,t.Orden) as Valor2
FROM Tabla t
```

el cual me genera este resultado

```
NumeroRegistro  Orden   Fecha       Valor        Valor2
473874             1    1/1/2023    100500  54811
473874             2    2/1/2023    99600   -44789
473874             3    3/1/2023    97500   -142289
473874             4    4/1/2023    80200   -222489
473874             5    5/1/2023    70900   -293389
473874             6    6/1/2023    65300   -358689
473874             7    7/1/2023    50300   -408989
```

lo que hace basicamente es agarrar el valor de la variable, y a esa variable le va restando el primer registros, luego a ese valor restado le resta el segundo registro y asi consecutivamente

lo que quiero es, como hacer para que el valor de la variable comience a realizar la resta a partir del 2 registro, y el primero registro que lo coloque null o 0

este es el resuletado que espero

```
NumeroRegistro  Orden   Fecha   Valor   Valor2
473874             1    1/1/2023    100500  0
473874             2    2/1/2023    99600   -53911
473874             3    3/1/2023    97500   -97500
473874             4    4/1/2023    80200   -80200
473874             5    5/1/2023    70900   -70900
473874             6    6/1/2023    65300   -65300
473874             7    7/1/2023    50300   -50300
```

como puedo realizar esto? necesito excluir el primer registro y que no se lo reste a la variable, si no que le comience a restar a partor del 2 registro

Answer (score 0):

El cálculo que quieres hacer es algo extraño, pero te dejo esta opción. Básicamente muestra el cálculo evitando la primer fila y solamente descontando mientras haya disponible del valor en @Total.

```
DECLARE @Total numeric(18,2) = 45689

SELECT 
        t.NumeroRegistro
        ,t.Orden
        ,t.Fecha
        ,t.Valor
        ,t.Valor2
        ,CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY t.Fecha,t.Orden)  = 1 
                THEN 0
              WHEN ABS( @Total 
                         - SUM(t.Valor) OVER( ORDER BY t.Fecha,t.Orden) 
                         + FIRST_VALUE(t.Valor) OVER( ORDER BY t.Fecha,t.Orden)) > Valor
                THEN -Valor
              ELSE @Total 
                    - SUM(t.Valor) OVER( ORDER BY t.Fecha,t.Orden) 
                    + FIRST_VALUE(t.Valor) OVER( ORDER BY t.Fecha,t.Orden) END AS Valor2
FROM Tabla t;
```